# How to solve NSInternalInconsistencyException: reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: (name != nil) && ([name length] > 0)'

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit, uinib

I get an `NSInternalInconsistencyException` when I use the OPPWAMobile payment library. I need to pass `name` somehow to `OPPPaymentSchemeViewController` so it passes it to `initWithNibName`. But I'm not sure how to do that in Xcode.

I've checked this [stack overflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18438768/assertion-failure-in-uinib-initwithnibnamedirectorybundle) but it didn't help because I don't have direct access to the view controller.

I'm sure that the nib name is part of a property file somewhere but I'm not able to locate it.

Any ideas on how to do that?

```
2021-06-22 08:24:27.468604+0300 Runner[6738:85985] *** Assertion failure in -[UINib initWithNibName:directory:bundle:], UINib.m:97
2021-06-22 08:25:12.078452+0300 Runner[6738:85985] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: (name != nil) && ([name length] > 0)'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20422fba __exceptionPreprocess + 242
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff20193ff5 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20422de3 +[NSException raise:format:] + 0
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff207748e7 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 191
    4   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff242b63de -[UINib initWithNibName:directory:bundle:] + 309
    5   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff242b6489 +[UINib nibWithNibName:bundle:] + 76
    6   OPPWAMobile                         0x00000001067e9736 -[OPPPaymentSchemeViewController registerTableViewCellNibs] + 153
    7   OPPWAMobile                         0x00000001067e9389 -[OPPPaymentSchemeViewController viewDidLoad] + 157
    8   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff23f806a9 -[UIViewController _sendViewDidLoadWithAppearanceProxyObjectTaggingEnabled] + 88
    9   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff23f8504c -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1084
    10  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff23f85436 -[UIViewController view] + 27
    11  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff23ec6559 -[UINavigationController _preferredContentSizeForcingLoad:] + 198
    12  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff23e64354 -[UIPresentationController preferredContentSizeDidChangeForChildContentContainer:] + 64
    13  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff23e6018f __56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke.466 + 178
    14  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff24bb1e36 -[_UIAfterCACommitBlock run] + 54
    15  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff246d01f8 _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 333
    16  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff246c01e4 _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 221
    17  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff246f1a36 _afterCACommitHandler + 85
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2038fd31 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2038a542 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 541
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2038aaf5 __CFRunLoopRun + 1129
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2038a1a7 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 567
    22  GraphicsServices                    0x00007fff2b874d85 GSEventRunModal + 139
    23  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff246c14df -[UIApplication _run] + 912
    24  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff246c639c UIApplicationMain + 101
    25  Runner                              0x00000001064fec8b main + 75
    26  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff2025abbd start + 1
)
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of2021-06-22 08:25:12.691736+0300 Runner[6738:88777] [] nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed
 type NSException
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: (name != nil) && ([name length] > 0)'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Where? `OPPWAMobile` is a xcframework. Precompiled and added as needed. I can't "pass" anything in the code. I'm sure OPPWAMobile looks up the `name` value from a properties files. but where?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, missed the `initWithNib:` part

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem. I needed to mark `OPPWAMobile.xcframework` as "Embed & Sign" under Target->General->Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content.

[image: Target->General->Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content]

I suspected that this may be the problem when I read the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621359-initwithnibname/) on how `initWithNibName:bundle:` behaves when `nibName` is nil.

> If you specify nil for the nibName parameter and you do not override
> the loadView method, the view controller **searches for a nib file as
> described in the nibName** property.

Which means that I was getting an exception because the framework couldn't find the necessary nib file.

Answer (score 0):

You have add `OPPWAMobile-Resources.bundle` on project.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else coming here later... this can also be caused if you call `super.init` in a custom initialiser of a `UIViewController` and enter `""` as the `nibName`:

❌

```
    init(foo: Foo) {
    self.foo = foo
    super.init(nibName: "", bundle: nil)
}
```

Instead, set the `nibName` to `nil`:

✅

```
    init(foo: Foo) {
    self.foo = foo
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition for adding the resource files and checking `Embed & Sign` in the general settings, Also make sure the order of the build phases are correct.

[image]