# MacOs Tkinter - App terminating 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: aString != nil'

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, py2app

When im launching my app via CLI, it works without issue

> ./org_chart.app/Contents/MacOS/org_chart

however when I launch via double click I met with the error

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: aString != nil'
```

I used py2app to build the app. Im not sure where to begin debugging this, if someone could point me in the right direction?

Thanks for your help!

here's the full code for the small app

```
import os, shutil
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox, Tk, Canvas, Entry, Text, Button, PhotoImage
from tkinter import font as tkFont

def build_org_chart():

    print("im making a chart")
  
    return 'Done chart created!'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = Tk()
    window.title("Org Chart Spreadsheet Generator")

    # Variables to store file paths
    window.geometry("1012x506")
    window.configure(bg = "#00403D")

    # Define the font properties
    my_font = tkFont.Font(family="Montserrat SemiBold", size=16, weight="normal")

    canvas = Canvas(
        window,
        bg = "#00403D",
        height = 506,
        width = 1012,
        bd = 0,
        highlightthickness = 0,
        relief = "ridge"
    )

    canvas.place(x = 0, y = 0)
    canvas.create_rectangle(
        308.0,
        0.0,
        1012.0,
        506.0,
        fill="#FFFFFF",
        outline="")

    canvas.create_text(
        320.0,
        18.0,
        anchor="nw",
        text="Org Chart",
        fill="#000000",
        font=("Montserrat Bold", 64 * -1)
    )

    window.resizable(False, False)
    window.mainloop()
```

Also now my app is so small its still crashing im thinking it could be something in the setup file too so ive added that code below

```
import os
from setuptools import setup

def list_files(directory):
    base_path = os.path.abspath(directory)
    paths = []
    for root, directories, filenames in os.walk(base_path):
        for filename in filenames:
            # Exclude .DS_Store files if you are on macOS
            if filename != '.DS_Store':
                paths.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
    return paths

# Your assets folder
assets_folder = 'assets'

# Listing all files in the assets folder
assets_files = list_files(assets_folder)

APP = ['org_chart_min.py']
DATA_FILES = [('assets', assets_files)]
OPTIONS = {
    'argv_emulation': True,

    'packages': ['pandas', 'openpyxl','xlsxwriter'],
        'plist': {
        'CFBundleName': '_org_chart',
        'CFBundleDisplayName': ' Org Chart',
        'CFBundleGetInfoString': "Create a spreadsheet that populates our Lucid org chart template",
        'CFBundleIdentifier': 'com.yourdomain.orgchart',
        'CFBundleVersion': '0.1',
        'CFBundleShortVersionString': '0.1',
        'NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance': True
    },
    'iconfile': 'org_chart.icns',
}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

Comment: You have way too much code. True removing parts while making sure it still crashes like that. That will make it a [mre] and will be easier for us to look through

Comment: Hi, ive done this, ive taken out 99% of the code, all it does is launch an almost blank window via the cli command now, and double clicking the app has the same error

Comment: Have a look, it might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68079786/how-to-solve-nsinternalinconsistencyexception-reason-invalid-parameter-not-sa

Comment: I used "python setup.py py2app". via CLI I don't set anything, I just run that command and it works, I double click the app icon and it crashes with the error above

Comment: macOS ventura, I build the file in an venv which is running 3.11.7, my Mac is running the same. however on my Mac I run python with the command python3, not python on its own. im not sure that matters who when just clicking an app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you use `pyinstaller`. It works for mac and it will compile an `UNIX` file. Just use `pip install pyinstaller` and after that in directory of your script `pyinstaller -F main.py`. Rename your file as `main.py` and it should compile one `UNIX` file. `-F` flag compiles it in one file. It works perfectly!

Comment: this just built a Linus file that opened in terminal, it didn't do anything after that? i.e. laugh the Tkinter window

Comment: i can give you the screenshot, it works. Did you compile the main script? You basically don't need the other script. Also, try removing the flag -F, it may work

Comment: I need to rename org_chart.py to main.py? I also have assets in my larger version I need to load into the package too, the app icon, images etc. can this be done with pyinstaller?

Comment: yes, you include the app icon with `-i iconname.ico` and you can load images directly from the code. Btw icon name can be anything

Comment: Check out the [documentation](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/)

Comment: @AlexW did it help? if it solved your problem say so

Comment: Ive finally got it to work using this! thanks for you help. my end command was "pyinstaller --windowed --onedir --icon=org_chart.icns --add-data "assets:assets" org_chart.py" for any that needs similar advice

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the line :

```
'argv_emulation': True,
```

From : https://py2app.readthedocs.io/en/stable/options.html

> WARNING: Do no use this option when the program uses a GUI toolkit. The emulator tends to confuse GUI toolkits, and most GUI toolkits have APIs to react to these events at runtime (for example to open a file when your program is already running).

Comment: @AlexW Does this solution fix your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

run this on terminal

```
rm ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Safari/Data/Library/Saved\ Application\ State/com.apple.Safari.savedState/windows.plist
```

This will reset Safari saved state, which is most probably the issue here.

Comment: this didn't work unfortunately. Run the command, typed yes. then tried to run the app again, same error